# Problema com rotas

Tags: javascript, node.js, express.js, nginx

Ao tentar acessar konic.com.br o site é carregado normalmente, mas quando entro em uma outra rota que no caso é konic.com.br/contato ele retorna 404

app.js:

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

app.use(express.static('html'));

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(__dirname, 'html/index.html');
});
app.get('/contato', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile (__dirname, 'html/contato.html');
    res.send("Deu certo");
});

app.listen(3002).on('listening', () => {
    console.log("Servidor rodando na porta 3002!");
});

module.exports = app;
```

/etc/nginx/sites-available/default

```
server {

    listen 443 ssl default_server;
    listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;


    root /var/www/konic.com.br/html;

    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name konic.com.br www.konic.com.br;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/konic.com.br/fullchain.pem; 
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/konic.com.br/privkey.pem;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://konic.com.br:3002;
        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

}


server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name lucasmrpires.com.br www.lucasmrpires.com.br;

    root /var/www/lucasmrpires.com.br/html;
    index index.html;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3003;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
}

server {
    if ($host = konic.com.br) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } 

    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    server_name konic.com.br www.konic.com.br;
    return 404; 


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quando você acessa konic.com.br, o Nginx responde adequadamente e manda para o seu navegador a sua aplicação javascript que está na raiz contendo as suas rotas. A partir daí, a navegação é toda controlada pelo JS.

No entanto, quando você tenta acessar qualquer outra URL, o Nginx está preparado para responder 404 quando uma pasta não existir (no seu exemplo não há uma pasta chamada /contato; esta é uma rota que foi definida pelo JS).

Repare que quem está preparado para responder às rotas é a aplicação JS da raiz, então é normal que qualquer chamada diferente da raiz retorne 404. Neste caso, será preciso adicionar uma regra no Nginx para sempre redirecionar para a raiz, de onde a aplicação será baixada e as rotas poderão ser acessadas.